# Press effect on image with css3

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

In my hybrid mobile app, I have multiple icons and I would like to reproduce a press effect when clicking on an icon.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon">
       <img src="img/menu.svg" />
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menuIcon {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 28px;
}

.menuIcon img {
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The press effect that I want to reproduce is visible into twitter app : You can see it here : **https://vid.me/gub5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that like this, using `transform: scale` and `:active`

```css
.menuIcon {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 28px;
}
.menuIcon img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.menuIcon img:active {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
 </div>
```